# android sdk not showing my mobile connected on usb port

Tags: usb, adb

I'm new to Android.
I'm using Micromax A87 (india) with Gingerbread, this company is not listed in Android Manufacturers on Google website. My mobile's USB debugging mode is on. I tried to run hello world program with Eclipse but it started in AVD.

My problem is that my mobile is not showing in list by adb devices command. But device manager (win7) shows android composite ADB interface and I can also use my phone as disk.

Tell me where is issue? If I try to install supplied driver with phone then PC say that I already have better drivers and same case is for online search. I tried restarting adb.

Please help me to set up android work-space.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue for the same handset, do the following...

1. Go to  C:\Users\system name.android
2. Make a copy of adb_usb.ini as a backup
3. Open adb_usb.ini
4. Replace the content of this file with following content:

```
0x17EF
0x1EBF
0x05C6
0x19D2
0x9015
0x1C9E
0x0BB4
```

Comment: how did you get to know that?

Comment: I got this solutions when i was searching for it and is working for my micromax a87. I dont have right now the source link and documentation...

Comment: In the ini file, it is written that running the command `android update adb` will update the ini file automatically and that we shouldn't be editing it manually. I ran the command and restarted adb sever, and the device started to appear.